# forefiles batch file to loop through terminal server profiles

Tags: rds, terminal-server

I am trying to create a batch script which will run through each users download folder on a terminal server and remove files older than 30 days

What I have so far is this

for /d %%a in (C:\Users*) do forfiles /p "%%a\Downloads" /D -30 /c "cmd /c del @path"

I want to excluded the desktop.ini file the batch script as it shows this line for each user for example:

Could Not Find C:\Users\Receiving\Downloads\desktop.ini

Comment: could you explain more also edit your question to more specific format

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add how what you have does not work, and what it does instead.